# Trying to access apolloClient in getServerSideProps context

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using Next.js 9.3.5 with Apollo and GraphQL for an SSR project I'm working on. I've implemented this example provided in the official pages:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-apollo/lib/apollo.js

So my page looks like this:

```
import { withApollo } from '../apollo/withApollo';

const Collections = (props) => {
   // ...
}

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ apolloClient }) => {
  console.log(apolloClient); // returns undefined

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};

export default withApollo()(Collections);
```

Problem is that `apolloClient` is not available inside `getServerSideProps`. But if I use `getInitialProps`, then it's working. The official Next.js doc says that we should be using `getServerSideProps`.

> If you're using Next.js 9.3 or newer, we recommend that you use
>   getStaticProps or getServerSideProps instead of getInitialProps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added `apolloClient` to NextPageContext and NextAppContext?

Comment: Do I have to do it manually? I'm still really new to next. How do I do that? I can't seem to find anything about it.

Comment: I've never done apollo + next neither, but `context` object by default doesn't have `apolloClient` prop, take look at this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9542#issuecomment-592187560

Comment: Can't figure it out ... I also tried replacing `getInitialProps` with `getServerSideProps` inside `withApollo`, but can't do that either: `getServerSideProps can not be attached to a page's component`

Comment: Hey Norbert, any solution for this?

Comment: @Leafyshark I eventually gave up and ended up using `getInitialProps`. Works great.

Answer (score 3):

I just use this and call in anywhere to get access to client in getServerSideProps

```
 export async function getStandaloneApolloClient() {
        const { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } = await import(
            "@apollo/client"
            );
        return new ApolloClient({
            link: new HttpLink({
                uri: process.env.BASE_URL,
                fetch
            }),
            cache: new InMemoryCache()
        });
    }
```